# How to perform mathematical operations in CloudFormation?

Tags: amazon-web-services, math, aws-cloudformation

Is it possible to perform some sort of mathematical operation in a CloudFormation template?

There are two areas that I've encountered where this would be useful:

1. Setting IOPS which needs to be a ratio of the disk size.
2. Setting CloudWatch Alarms for RDS Free Storage Space. It would be useful to set this as a % of the disk size.

Answer (score 16):

There are two general solutions to performing custom logic in CloudFormation templates not supported by [Intrinsic Functions](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSCloudFormation/latest/UserGuide/intrinsic-function-reference.html), such as mathematical operations:

#### 1. Custom Resource

Write a [Custom Resource](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSCloudFormation/latest/UserGuide/template-custom-resources.html) to execute your mathematical operation, passing inputs as Properties and outputs as Values. Here's a self-contained working example that returns `Result: 13` as a Stack Output:

[image: Launch Stack]

```
Resources:
  LambdaExecutionRole:
    Type: AWS::IAM::Role
    Properties:
      AssumeRolePolicyDocument:
        Version: '2012-10-17'
        Statement:
        - Effect: Allow
          Principal: {Service: [lambda.amazonaws.com]}
          Action: ['sts:AssumeRole']
      Path: "/"
      ManagedPolicyArns:
      - arn:aws:iam::aws:policy/service-role/AWSLambdaBasicExecutionRole
  AddFunction:
    Type: AWS::Lambda::Function
    Properties:
      Handler: index.handler
      Role: !GetAtt LambdaExecutionRole.Arn
      Code:
        ZipFile: !Sub |
          var response = require('cfn-response');
          exports.handler = function(event, context) {
            var result = parseInt(event.ResourceProperties.Op1) + parseInt(event.ResourceProperties.Op2);
            response.send(event, context, response.SUCCESS, {Value: result});
          };
      Runtime: nodejs
  AddTest:
    Type: Custom::Add
    Properties:
      ServiceToken: !GetAtt AddFunction.Arn
      Op1: 8
      Op2: 5
Outputs:
  Result:
    Description: Result
    Value: !GetAtt AddTest.Value
```

#### 2. Template Preprocessor

Use a full-featured templating language/platform of your choice to write a 'source' template that produces a valid CloudFormation-template as output. You can use a full-featured CloudFormation-specific library like [troposphere](https://github.com/cloudtools/troposphere), but it's also easy enough to write a simple preprocessor layer to suit your use-case and programming-language/library preferences.

My current choice is embedded Ruby ([ERB](http://ruby-doc.org/stdlib/libdoc/erb/rdoc/ERB.html)), mostly because I'm already familiar with it. Here's an example `template.yml.erb` file using embedded Ruby syntax to perform a mathematical operation that returns `Result: 13` as a Stack Output:

```
Resources:
  # CloudFormation stacks require at least one resource
  Dummy:
    Type: AWS::SNS::Topic
Outputs:
  Result:
    Description: Result
    Value: <%= 8 + 5 %>
```

To process the template, run `cat template.yml.erb | ruby -rerb -e "puts ERB.new(ARGF.read, nil, '-').result" > template.yml`, which will write the following CloudFormation-ready template to `template.yml`:

```
Resources:
  # CloudFormation stacks require at least one resource
  Dummy:
    Type: AWS::SNS::Topic
Outputs:
  Result:
    Description: Result
    Value: 13
```

Comment: In the first example, does that spin up an entire lambda function just to do 5+8?

Comment: @PaulaT you got it

Comment: Seems a bit excessive, and expensive if the service experiences frequent deployments.

Comment: Lambda cost is about 22 cents per million invocations for a simple function, so prefer option 2 if that cost is excessive for your use case.

Answer (score 5):

Much later in 2022...

This is one reason for using [CDK](https://aws.amazon.com/cdk/), which provides a code wrapper (e.g. Javascript, Typescript etc.) over CloudFormation and makes calculations, conditionals sharing etc. much simpler than is possible when only using CloudFormation templates.

Answer (score 1):

Is it still a hack if you limit the range of the StartingValue?

```
Parameters:
  StartingValue:
    MinValue: 0
    MaxValue: 7
    Type: Number
Outputs:
  MinusOne:
    Value: !Select [ !Ref StartingValue, ["-1","0","1","2","3","4","5","6"] ]
  PlusOne:
    Value: !Select [ !Ref StartingValue, ["1","2","3","4","5","6","7","8"] ]
  TimesTwo:
    Value: !Select [ !Ref StartingValue, ["0","2","4","6","8","10","12","14"] ]
```

https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSCloudFormation/latest/UserGuide/intrinsic-function-reference-select.html

Answer (score 0):

I've had great success with using a pre-processing system.  In general I'm looking at the template and the variable data and making decisions based on these pieces of data.

Here's a blog post on the problem:

http://krogebry.blogspot.com/2014/12/cloudformation-discovery-and.html

At the time of writing we had an issue with many VPC's and a very complicated system of account management.  What you're saying seem like it might be of a similar vein of thinking in that you have some complicated ( and neat! ) requirements that might require a similar approach.  Also, compiling a stack like this has the added benefit of being able to enforce certain rules ( like no 0.0.0.0:22 or no IOPS>x threshold in dev ) all based on your use case.

Comment: Unfortunately, this link doesn't work anymore.